# AWK error argument is out of the range? How to solve this problem?

Tags: bash, awk

This is part of my file

```
4.997 0.0110329
4.998 0.0110245
4.999 0.0110324
5 0.0110272
```

When I run my script"

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{$2=((0.231771*exp(-$1/0.00142118)+0.299638*exp(-$1/0.0500264)+0.318124*exp(-$1/0.332495)+0.150467*exp(-$1/1.8087))-$2); print}' lut_ver_eps_900_1100_v5.xvg | tee lut_ver_eps_900_1100_v5_roznice.xvg
```

I get an error like

```
1: (FILENAME=lut_ver_eps_900_1100_v5.xvg FNR=5001) ostrzeżenie: exp: argument -3518.2 jest poza zasięgiem
```

Translate to English

```
1: (FILENAME=lut_ver_eps_900_1100_v5.xvg FNR=5001) warning: exp: argument -3518.2 is out of range
```

What I should change?

I get the result

```
4.997 -0.00153571
4.998 -0.00153256
4.999 -0.00154571
5 -0.00154575
```

but I don't know that everything is fine

Comment: Please reduce your code/example to just a minimal statement that reproduces your problem. We don't need to see 20 lines of input and a bunch of awk statements and a pipe to tee for you to show us just the specific problem you're asking for help with. Just figure out the minimal code to reproduce the problem and post that.

Comment: I see you got rid of some extraneous stuff but it's still nowhere near a [mcve]. Here is a [mcve] just based on your data: `awk 'BEGIN{print exp(-4.997/0.00142118)}'` outputs
`awk: cmd. line:1: warning: exp: argument -3516.09 is out of range`. Everything else in your question just hides the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exp(-1300)` would evaluate to a very small value very close to 0. It is so small that the result of the calculation cannot be represented in the machine's floating point format. Probably awk is outputting '0', which, depending on your goal, may be fine.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

[`exp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Numeric-Functions.html) does

> Return the exponential of *x* (`e ^ x`) or report an error if *x* is out of
> range. The range of values *x* can have depends on your machine’s
> floating-point representation.

if you do not want to have errors, but rather zero you might replace e.g.

```
exp(-10000)
```

using

```
2.7183^(-10000)
```

after replacing `2.7183` with *e* approximation close enough for your needs